# jQueryUI Sorting issue when width of all list items is not equal

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have an issue while sorting the list items when width if all the `<li>` is not equal. In the example below I try to place "Item 6" just after "Item 4" to no avail.

```js
$('#sort').sortable({ 
    
});
```

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #0f0;
    width: 25%;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
    height: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sort">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li style="width:100%;">Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you make this issue more clear to us ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you still can put Item 6 after Item 4 (eg. put Item 6 before Item 4 first then move it after Item 4). It's just a bit difficult. Adding [grid](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-grid) option makes it easier. Try to run this snippet:

```js
$('#sort').sortable({ 
    grid: [ 10, 10 ]
});
```

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #0f0;
    width: 25%;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
    height: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sort">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li style="width:100%;">Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```